# Can't reference variable outside of for loop

Tags: apex, class, map

I am trying to see if the map is changed (rate_card__c) and then query all of the members associated with that id. And update with the rate card. We have business accounts and people accounts a person account is a child via a look-up to an employer record. Do I need to create something else to call the variable I already used?

```apex
public static void updateRateCard (List<Account> oldAcc, List<Account> newAcc, Map<Id, Account> oldAccMap, Map<Id, Account> newAccMap) {
    String memberRecTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Member').getRecordTypeId();
    //create set of accounts 
    List<String> accountSet = new List<String>();
    List<Account> memberAccts = new List<Account>();
    system.debug('-----' );
    for(Account a: newAcc) {
        if (a.Rate_Card__c <> oldAccMap.get(a.Id).Rate_Card__c ) {
            accountSet.add(a.Id);
        }
    }
        
    if (accountSet.size() > 0) {
        memberAccts = [SELECT Id, Rate_Card__c FROM Account WHERE Employer__c IN :accountSet AND Employer__c != null];
        if ( memberAccts.size() > 0 ) {
            for (Account memberacct: memberAccts) {
                memberacct.Rate_Card__c = accountSet.get(a.Rate_Card__c);
            }
            try { 
                update memberAccts;
            } catch (DMLException e) {
                system.debug('@#@ DML Error: ' + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The account set holds Account IDs (as a list, not a set?) but you then try to get a value from the set using a rate card ID...? I am not really clear what the code is trying to do. Please [edit] the question to explain. I get the feeling you should be using a map of some form, but it depends on exactly what this code is supposed to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to see if the map is changed (rate_card__c) then query all of the members associated with that id. And update with the rate card. We have business accounts and people accounts a person account is a child via a look up to an employer record.

Answer (score -1):

In this line:

```apex
memberacct.Rate_Card__c = accountSet.get(a.Rate_Card__c);
```

you are using `a`, but `a` is a local variable. You can not use local variable outside the block , So
You can directly get the data using get method.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Your contribution is welcome, but your answer could be greatly improved if you would better explain what you mean by "local variable" (talk a little about scope) and what you mean by "You can directly get the data using get method," and give an example/code sample of using it correctly. Please click "Edit" where you see "Share Edit Follow Flag" on the bottom left of your answer to edit your question and add that additional information.

Comment: @rohit-bhalla would I have to create an additional map on this to call?